# Running an existing tkinter script from another tkinter script

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm new to python and tkinter.

I have a working tkinter script (Which I would like to avoid editing)
Now I'm writing a script which will be top level GUI.
The button from this script should launch my existing script with some command line arguments (like running it from a shell i.e. python3.4.1 script.py args).

I have tried the following:

1. Using os.system

   ```
   btn2 = Button(frame2, text="Configure>>", command="os.system('python script.py args')")
   ```
2. Using subprocess

   ```
   def runSubProcess(self):
       p=subprocess.Popen(["python3.4.1","script.py args"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
       output=p.communicate()[0]
   ```

Both methods are not working.

Any suggestions are welcome and thanks.

Edit: Also I don't need to communicate with the new window, as it'll be writing to a file which will be used later. Just the control return from child to parent window should suffice (upon clicking OK)

-Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method should work. However, you passed the wrong thing to the `command` argument for the Button. You should pass a function to the command instead of a string. You can use lambda:

```
btn2 = Button(frame2, text="Configure>>", command=lambda: os.system('python script.py args'))
```

Comment: Hi, 
It worked with lambda. 
I also got it working using subprocess.call('python script args', shell=true).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am glad it worked. If you think this answer is helpful, you can choose to upvote and/or accept this answer (click on the check-symbol on the left.)